# Can I compile c++ code 32bit with 64bit Cygwin, using multilib and -m32?

Tags: c++, cygwin, 32bit-64bit

How can I compile c++ for 32bit architectures using 64bit Cygwin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can't use multilib nor -m32**. You will have to install the package cygwin32-gcc-g++ or use 32bit cygwin for this.

> x86_64-pc-cygwin does 64bit Cygwin, it does not support multilib nor
>   -m32, it will not do so in the future either, so don't argue about
>   adding support. "g++" in 64bit Cygwin targets 64bit Cygwin.
>
> Use 32bit Cygwin or the 32 Cygwin cross compiler in 64bit Cygwin
>   instead. I don't really understand why this is so hard to grasp.

[Source](https://www.cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2013-10/msg00312.html)